# How to use curl for non-interactive repetitive task - Downloading a sales CSV file 20 times per day

Tags: linux, bash, curl

I see curl examples around on the Internet. But I'm just landing on tutorials on how to use Linux bash - curl to post messages to Facebook and other simpler starter help, but seeking more now.

I work in Operations for a marketing company. One of my jobs is to log into the sales website CRM (Customer Relationship Manager) system and download the orders each morning.

It takes about 25 mouse clicks to get the CSV sales downloaded for one product. there are dozens of products! As you might imagine, half my day is spent mouse clicking through the web based ordering system for hours. While the job security is nice, I'd like to get those steps automated so I can clear time for more server administration tasks.

Here is a process flow, exact steps for what the human operator must to to retrieve these sales orders:

Process flow:

1. log into https://www.the-sales-crm-example.com/admin/login.php
2. pass username password information
3. click Clients and Fulfillment (top nav bar)
4. dropdown to Prospects
5. click the 'arrow' for advanced searching
6. set date from: (yesterday example 07/10/2014
7. set date to: (today example 07/11/2014)
8. click the search button
9. 700+ records (sales orders) found
10. screen only displays 10 at a time
11. click the 'show' triangle and dropdown to 1000
12. now all 700 records show
13. click the 'select all' box at the top
14. all 700 records now have checks in the boxes
15. click export CSV
16. The CSV file contains all 700 sales orders.

Basic things I've tried to get started.

1. Launch Google chrome, visit the sales website, and hit F12 to see source code.
2. Example website sales-whatever dot com
3. Source for login.php - look for Username and Password field in the code.
4. User/Pass looks like javascript embedded in the login.php file
   It looks like 'admin_name" and "admin_pass" are variables I should be passing data to, am I right?

TRYING THIS

---

I'm already kinda falling down here, I'm not sure how I'd pass a username/password into the sales ordering website. 
I've read about cookie jars, getting lost in YouTube curl tutorials:

```
curl --cookie-jar cjar --output /dev/null website dot com
curl --cookie cjar --cookie-jar cjar --data 'name=Chucky' --data 'pass=ZzChuckyZZ' --
location website dot com
```

---

Any front to back examples or help would be appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: You're getting lost because you're not looking for the right info. curl will not help you drive a Web app through the UI. You need to find out if the CRM has an API. Most CRMs worth their salt have APIs designed for automation such as you're describing. If it does you could possibly use curl. If you have no other options than the UI I would suggest using Java with some libraries.

Comment: A website *is* an API. It may just not be a very friendly one. You can always script it. It may just be very very unpleasant. You are likely going to want to look at using the developer tools for chrome or firefox and having them record the entire transaction set one morning. Making note of when you take certain important actions. Then you will be able to look at that request log data and see if you can abstract it into the appropriate automated requests.

Comment: @EtanReisner: I respectfully disagree and would suggest the OP not follow that advice. Trying a set of curl hacks is likely a journey down a nasty rabbit hole. Modern CRMs have Web APIs that could accomplish the OP's task with a single call. Definitely start by looking there. What CRM are you using by the way?

Comment: I agree with @PaulSasik , UI is subject to frequent changes and it might break your code easily if a minor change took place in the UI.

Comment: I said nothing about navigating any UI. I said a website is an API. Which it is. There is a request and response. If you have to follow a flow that's a bad API and one that will cause pain but that's not different than half of the actual libraries that exist in the world. I said, find the requests you need to make and make those. For many well designed websites those will, quite literally, be the actual documented API requests.

Comment: Hi Paul Sasik, the CRM is called Limelight. Basic info about it is at limelightcrm dot com. I'm just finishing my day now, I literally logged into Limelight 24 times today loading up leads for everything from Weightloss to Skincare products. Maybe I should contact the technical support team for the Weighloss Limelight product and ask if they have a backend way of passing website leads directly to an FTP client on our Linux box so I don't have to keep logging in by hand and killing my wrists.

Comment: This sounds like web automation; e.g. you could use Selenium to do the mentioned tasks. But, like you said, it would be even better if the folks at limelightcrm provide you the necessary support.

Comment: I did try that Chromium Browser Automation. Click RECORD, make my 35 mouseclicks needed to get a CSV sales dump. Then I'd click PLAY. The browser automation wouldn't get past the Limelight login page, it would just loop and stay hung on the first login.html. One thing I did find out is Limelight already sends live leads every 15 minutes to our ACD (Automated Call Distributor). But our ACD provider can't scrub the phone numbers against the Federal do not call list so the ACD API collects phone numbers but we have to scrub the data anyway. I want that 15 minute data coming to me, not the ACD.

Comment: After you have done all of the b.s. to download your csv, but before it is actually downloaded, you should get a URI (either in browser nav bar, by js inspector or right-click in the download menu for the actual link).  That is what you need for your curl automation ... usually it is a get request resembling a form submission with `?var=value&output=csv` ...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't care if someone can sniff out your username and password from server logs, perhaps try `curl <options> https://websitename.com?username=<username>&password=<password>` for the login part.  You might want to look into AutoIT to catch your keystrokes and automate the process.